# How to create transparent areas in a UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

i'm creating a game for iPhone, with xcode. I have a starting image, from which i'd like to have a second image with some (four) transparent areas in it, e.g. just like this one:

[image]

The problem is that i don't know how to achieve it; have i to handle the original image and to cut the areas from it? or have i to create a new image where i put only the visible parts from the original one?
Any suggestion or snippet would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd do it by creating custom UIView subclass and using its drawRect method to draw the portion. 
Fo example:

-(void)drawRect:(

```
CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); // get drawing context

    CGContextSaveGState(ctx); //remember current state
    CGContextClipToRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)); //set clipping
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height), img.CGImage);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx); //restore state, so the previous clipping will be canceled

    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextClipToRect(ctx, CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100));
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height), img.CGImage);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}
```

This will draw two small rects. In this code img is an UIImage.

However, this is the easiest way to do this, not the most efficient - it requres to redraw for each portion. You might want to check CGContextClipToRects and CGContextClip functions, to make it more efficient and flexible.

Comment: Oh, many thanks. It works (even if the two small rects appear upside down...) Anyway a very good start point ;)

Comment: And i solved it replacing CGContextDrawImage with [img drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)] ... :)